# Unexpected result when reversing cstring with pointer notation

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I'm passing two c-strings (one containing characters, the other one empty) to a function that is supposed to take the c-string that contains characters and populate the empty c-string with the string read from behind. Simple operation, but it doesn't work. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void magic(char*, const char*, int);

int main()
{
   char string1[20];
   char string2[] = "This is a test";
   char *str1 = string1; 
   char *str2 = string2;
   int stringsize = strlen(string2);
   magic(str1, str2, stringsize);
   return 0;
}

void magic(char* string1, const char* string2, int stringsize)
{
   cout << string2 << endl; //here it prints as expected
   *(string1 + stringsize) = '\0';
   string1 = string1 + stringsize - 1;
   for(;*string2 != '\0' ;string1--, string2++)
   {
      *string1 = *string2;
   }
   cout << string1 << endl; //blank space is printed - expected "This is a test" reversed
   cout << string2 << endl; //blank space is printed - expected "This is a test" 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know that arrays decays naturally to pointers? So there's no need for the temporary `str1` and `str2` variables, just pass the arrays as is to the function.

Comment: @Joachim. I'm aware, but I wanted to create a function that used pointers instead of simple arrays, so I might have complicated things more than strictly necessary but I still don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Please decide: Are your strings 0-terminated, or are they counted. Mixing those is generally a bad idea... and your *magic*-function is very much unsure about it.

Comment: The function can take pointer still, even if you pass arrays. Even if you declare a function argument as e.g. `char string1[20]` it will *still* be a pointer. As for your problem, now might be a good time to learn how to use a debugger, because with a debugger you can step through code, line by line, and watch variables and their values and how they change. That will help you a lot with problems like this.

Comment: @WykoW In the `magic` function, why would you expect `string2` to point to the beginning of the string when you are changing where it points to in the loop?  That should give you a clue -- print the arrays *after* `magic` returns.

Comment: @Paul. That was the problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Joachim. Yes, that is a good suggestion. I'm just used to running programs from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the problem in your logic if you follow the steps in the `for` loop using a very simple string. Let's say,

```
string1 = "This";
```

In the first iteration of the loop,

```
string1 = "This";
string2 = "T";
```

In the second iteration of the loop,

```
string1 = "his";
string2 = "hT";
```

In the third iteration of the loop,

```
string1 = "is";
string2 = "ihT";
```

In the fourth iteration of the loop,

```
string1 = "s";
string2 = "sihT";
```

In the fifth iteration of the loop,

```
string1 = "";
string2 = "?sihT";  // You go past the start of the array.
```

Hence, after the `for` loop ends, you need to increment `string2` to make sure it points to the start of the array.

```
void magic(char* string1, const char* string2, int stringsize)
{
   cout << string2 << endl;
   *(string1 + stringsize) = '\0';
   string1 = string1 + stringsize-1;
   for(;*string2 != '\0' ;string1--, string2++)
   {
      *string1 = *string2;
   }

   // Add this.
   string1++;

   cout << string1 << endl; // This is now the reversed string.
   cout << string2 << endl; // This is now the empty string since
                            // you kept incrementing it in the for
                            // loop until you reached the end of the
                            // string.
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. string1 ended up being out of bounds. I knew it was a a small detail that caused `cout` to print nothing.